# Take a ScreenShot of Div Containing rotated Images and importing div image into a PDF file

Tags: css, pdf

I have a parent div containing some child divs which are rotated using transform: rotate(-18deg); and i have put images on those child divs.
Now i want a screenshot this parent div and import that picture to pdf.
I am getting the screenshot using html2canvas. but the child divs are not rotated since html2canvas does not support transform.
I tried directly importing div to pdf using mpdf  but that is too worse since mpdf partially supports css.

Can anyone find a solution.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is download [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/). The new nightly version makes it possible to  actually select a specific part of your code within the developer tool and save it as an image.

See example here: [image: How to screenshot a specific part of your code]

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i want the screenshot on click of a button. I mean through coding and not manually